# Alias Name issue in SNowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using a single query:

```
(SELECT *,'{"Source": "010","Keys": [{"Value": "CHARGE"}]}' AS ID1 
FROM DETAILS) metrics
JOIN DIM.TYPE trant
ON metrics.ID1 = trant.BK_TRANSACTIONTYPE
```

But I am getting this error:

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 3 at position 30 unexpected
> 'metrics'.

Please advise how it can be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try with below query. Hope it works :)

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *,'{"Source": "010","Keys": [{"Value": "CHARGE"}]}' AS ID1 FROM DETAILS) metrics JOIN DIM.TYPE trant ON metrics.ID1 = trant.BK_TRANSACTIONTYPE
```